# Make GuiText responsive

Tags: c#, unity, gui, unityscript

I'm using C# code to make a responsive GuiText.
I was abel to make a responsive GuiTexture, but I'm struggling with doing the same for a GuiText.

Code for the responsive GuiTexture

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ResponsiveGUITexture : MonoBehaviour {
    public float designScreenWidth = 800, designScreenHeight = 480;
    public bool debugMode = false;

    private Rect pixelInset0;

    void Start () {
        pixelInset0 = this.guiTexture.pixelInset;
        this.guiTexture.pixelInset = new Rect(Screen.width / designScreenWidth * pixelInset0.x, Screen.height / designScreenHeight * pixelInset0.y, Screen.width / designScreenWidth * pixelInset0.width, Screen.height / designScreenHeight * pixelInset0.height);
    }

    void Update(){
        if(debugMode){
            this.guiTexture.pixelInset = new Rect(Screen.width / designScreenWidth * pixelInset0.x, Screen.height / designScreenHeight * pixelInset0.y, Screen.width / designScreenWidth * pixelInset0.width, Screen.height / designScreenHeight * pixelInset0.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Responsive to what?? Screen resolution? Or something else? I don't understand your question

Comment: @Mitananda PLEASE SHARE THE SOLUTION IF U HAVE FOUND

Answer (score -1):

Once I did a little API to do what I wanted to do, and it worked, it's not finished, but, it could help you out. Use your creativity, and make new things to this API ;)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

/*
 * @author: Rafael C. Nunes
 * @email: rafaelnunes737@hotmail.com
 * 
 * @version: 0.1
 * @date: 08/02/2014
 * 
 * 
 * This archive is the screen API, that provide a screen configuration of the PC.
 * By default, all the elements that are instantiated on the screen will be on     the    left.
 * 
 */

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class _screen : MonoBehaviour
{
//Return the screen width and height
public int getScreenWidth
{ 
    get 
    {
        return Screen.width;
    } 
}
public int getScreenHeight
{
    get
    {
        return Screen.height;
    }
} 

/*
 * helping the programmer/designer to position the elements on the screen, positionLeft is the 
 * position left of the screen, the positionMiddle is the center of the screen positionRight is 
 * the position right of the screen, it is just a draw. 
 */
public int positionLeft 
{
    get 
    {
        return Screen.width - Screen.width;
    }
}
public int positionMiddle
{
    get
    {
        return Screen.width / 2;
    }
}
public int positionRight
{
    get
    {
        return Screen.width;
    }
}

private int screenWidth = Screen.width;
private int screenHeight = Screen.height;

public void setCursor(Texture2D texture, Vector2 hotspot, CursorMode cursor)
{
    UnityEngine.Cursor.SetCursor(texture, hotspot, cursor);
}


public bool createButton(float left, float top, float width, float height, String value) 
{
    return GUI.Button(new Rect((screenWidth-screenWidth)+left, (screenHeight-screenHeight)+top, 
                                                                        width, height), value);
}

public bool createRepeatButton(float left, float top, float width, float height, String value)
{
    return GUI.RepeatButton(new Rect(left, top, width, height), value);
}

public void createLabel(float left, float top, float width, float height, String value) 
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect((screenWidth - screenWidth)+left, (screenHeight - screenHeight)+top, 
                                                                    width, height), value);
}
}
```

Comment: Your comment has no relation to the question. How is your code responsive to what?

Comment: Responsive to the window of the game. I supposed that the OP was asking for this.

Comment: And it's not one hundred per cent precise.